# Apache2, can't apply Directory access

Tags: apache-2.2

i can't figure out how apply deny access to a directory.
Here is my config:

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80> 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wwwhtml 
ServerName mydomain.com 
ServerAdmin it@mydomain.com 
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_error.log 
TransferLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_access_log

Alias /test /var/www/html/wwwhtml/eventum  
<Directory /var/www/html/wwwhtml/eventum>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        #Allow from 192.168.0  
</Directory>
```

I deny access to /test but it doesn't work, on my another server it works perfectly :/
Do you know what can cause that problem? How to solve it?
It is not whole config but the most important part.
Maybe file rewrites can cause it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem a bit obvious, but you did remember to restart Apache right?

Comment: Yep, it's pretty obvious :]

Comment: There was <Location> directive with allow grant, what induce overwritting... Solved